# How do I setup a game with my friends?

Tags: diablo-iii

It's obviously more efficient to use Infernal Machines together because one set of keys can be used by multiple people at once.  But you want to have Monster Power turned on to improve drop rates for the Organs, and Monster Power cannot be enabled with public games. So how do I create a non-public game with my friends? Do I need to know the user's username or their number too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to know each others battletag and add them to your friends list. Then its a simple matter of joining your friends game or [a inviting them to yours](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/playing-with-friends).

Comment: What's my battle tag? My user name is letstrade.

Comment: The battle tag is your id on Battle.net followed with a hash and a four digit no.

For example, my battle tag is kidakaka#2329

Comment: where do you see that? I login and I couldn't find it. My battle tag is letstrade I think. I forget the number.

Comment: A google search helped me find your tag, its letstrade#1757

Comment: When you are logged into Diablo III, you can press the "O" button to bring up your social menu, inside there, you will see your Battle Tag. For you, it'd be something like "Letstrade#xxxx"

Comment: there are many other letstrade. How do you know I am the one with 1757? Thanks. I also want to add a subforum in battle.net where people do fine friends for hellfire ring run.